# Spring data Elasticsearch : Reinitialise elasticsearch hosts/cluster_password programmatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

TL;DR : How to switch elastic search hosts at runtime using spring-data-elasticsearch?

We have a spring boot application (v : 2.5.2) using spring data elasticsearch (v: 4.2.2).

I am using java configurations to initialize ES connection as mentioned in [High Level Rest Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest) section of spring's documentation.

We have a requirement where we need to change the elasticsearch hosts at runtime and not manually restart our servers.

I tried restarting spring IOC on hostname config change using something similar to spring actuator's [RestartEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/main/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/restart/RestartEndpoint.java). But this seems to work only in spring's embedded tomcat and not with the external tomcat that we use.

Is there an alternate way to do this?

[This is required in case there is a disaster and we need to switch to backup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing out of the box.

One idea (I did not try it out): You'd need to create your own implementation of the `ElasticsearchOperations` interface, lets call it `MyOperations` and return that from the `AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration#elasticsearchOperations()` method which your configuration inherits. In this `MyOperations` implementation (which is a singleton Spring bean), you'd create a delegate `ElasticsearchOperations` with the same code like in the configuration class that is connected to normal cluster. Every method in your implementation then delegates to the corresponding method of the delegate.

In the failure case, your implementation would create a new delegate that now connects to the secondary cluster and replace the first one with it. Or create both and implement a toggle feature to switch between the two.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a 'spring way' to refresh all the ES related beans programmatically. Something like recreating all the ES auto configuration, the way it happens on application startup.
I tried making scope  of AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration beansto protptype, and make the instances of restClient etc as singleton in my code manually(bypassing CGLIB).
But this results in incorrect query results.

Comment: BTW, the delegate approach works!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the answer provided by P.J.Meisch,

Create a custom implementation for `ElasticsearchOperations`

```
public class CustomElasticsearchOperations implements ElasticsearchOperations {
private ElasticsearchOperations delegateElasticSearchOp;

    /**
     * Main Constructor to create the instance using existing elasticsearchConverter bean
     * @param elasticsearchConverter : ElasticsearchConverter
     */
    public CustomElasticsearchOperations(ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter) {
        updateElasticsearchOperationDelegate(elasticsearchConverter);
    }


    private ElasticsearchOperations createNewElasticsearchOperationDelegate(ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter){
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(ElasticsearchRestHighLevelClientProvider.INSTANCE.elasticsearchClient(),elasticsearchConverter);
    }

    /**
     * Method to update the delegate ElasticsearchRestTemplate to register elasticsearch configurations
     * @param elasticsearchConverter : Default spring lib provided ElasticsearchConverter instance
     */
    public void updateElasticsearchOperationDelegate(ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter){
        this.delegateElasticSearchOp = createNewElasticsearchOperationDelegate(elasticsearchConverter);
    }

    /*
     * ElasticsearchOperations method implementation using Delegate ElasticsearchRestTemplatea
     */

    @Override
    public IndexOperations indexOps(Class<?> aClass) {
        return delegateElasticSearchOp.indexOps(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public IndexOperations indexOps(IndexCoordinates indexCoordinates) {
        return delegateElasticSearchOp.indexOps(indexCoordinates);
    }

    @Override
    public ClusterOperations cluster() {
        return delegateElasticSearchOp.cluster();
    }

    @Override
    public ElasticsearchConverter getElasticsearchConverter() {
        return delegateElasticSearchOp.getElasticsearchConverter();
    }
    // And so on... delegate the impl of overriden method to existing ElasticsearchRestTemplate

}
```

Where `ElasticsearchRestHighLevelClientProvider` is a class that holds the logic to create object of `RestHighLevelClient` that holds the values for current cluster configurations

```
// This is a sample from spring documentation. Create your own rest client with your own configs
public enum ElasticsearchRestHighLevelClientProvider{
    INSTANCE; 
    // below is a sample, change it according to your requirements.
       
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
         String hosts [] = getLatestConfigs().getHosts();
         final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = 
         ClientConfiguration.builder()  
            .connectedTo(hosts)
            .build();

         return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();       


    }
    // your code for fetching cluster configs.. 

}
```

And finally, register the bean of `CustomElasticsearchOperations`

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchAutoConfigurations  extends ElasticsearchConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean(
            name = {"elasticsearchOperations", "elasticsearchTemplate"}
    )
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations(ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter) {
        return new CustomElasticsearchOperations(elasticsearchConverter);
    }
}
```

Now when your configurations change you can Autowire the instances of `ElasticsearchOperations` and `ElasticsearchConverter`  beans, and invoke `ElasticsearchOperations#updateElasticsearchOperationDelegate(elasticsearchConverter)`

This will replace the instance of `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` within `CustomElasticsearchOperations` singleton bean with the new configs, and new requests will go to the cluster you want to switch to.

Note that

- If you have autowired `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` to make non spring repository based calls to elasticsearch, change the autowired candidate to parent interface `ElasticsearchOperations` as `ElasticsearchRestTemplate`'s instance will not be present in the application context
- `ElasticsearchConverter` is already created within `ElasticsearchConfigurationSupport` class. So no need to create this bean again