# How to connect to multiple servers in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use the following configuration for elastic and I want to use multiple addresses instead of one

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
class Config {

@Bean
fun client(): RestHighLevelClient {
    val clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("127.0.0.1:9200")
            .build()

    return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest()
}

@Bean
fun elasticsearchTemplate(): ElasticsearchOperations {
    return ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client())
}
```

}

Comment: fyi, rest high level client is deprecated in es 7.15

Comment: different addresses in the same cluster for redundance or multiple clusters?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch in the same client

Comment: @Amit The Java High Level REST Client is the default client of Elasticsearch, it provides a straight forward replacement for the TransportClient as it accepts and returns the very same request/response objects

Comment: @RaminAsadi JHLRC was deprecated in favour of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html , which provided even better functionality :)

Comment: the same client, but targeting the same cluster?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch yes, same cluster

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70618247/spring-data-elasticsearch-reinitialise-elasticsearch-hosts-cluster-password-pr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple `host:port` Strings to the `connectedTo()` method:

```java
ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo("IP_1:PORT_1", "IP_2:PORT_2")
            .build()
```